# how to change dynamic page template title on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have a page template on wordpress for fund details from an api, the pages that use the template arent a real wordpress pages and i cant edit the pages title from wordress.
wordpress use the page template title and i need it to use the fund name of any fund from database as a title for this dynamic pages, same thing with page description.
*i'm using yoast in my website.

url of random fund in my website - https://getwiser.co.il/vtest-detail?id=7989

i put this code on functions.php , but it didnt work

```
if ( is_page(14797) ) {
function custom_document_title( $title ) {
    return <?= $get_data_spec->FUND_NAME?>;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'custom_document_title', 10 );
}
```

Comment: Not sure if `is_page` already works in the functions.php. Try and do this the other way around - add the filter function in any case, and then inside the function, check if you are on your specific target page (and if not, just return $title)

Comment: I have no idea what you are event trying to ask there now with that latest comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Any error displayed?